# Can I inject into an ASP.NET MVC controller, some strings (eg. configuration values) using StructureMap?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap

I'm using structureMap as my IoC/DI for an ASP.NET MVC web site. Works great.

Normally, I have my controllers that pass in Interfaces and structureMap + greedy constructors == works great.

eg.

```
public void FooController : Controller
{
    public FooController(IPewPew pewPew) { .. }
}
```

etc..

But.. one of my controllers (and only one of em) would like to have two strings to be passed in.

eg..

```
public void FooController2 : Controller
{
    public FooController2(IPewPew pewPew, string aaa, string bbb) { .. }
}
```

Is there any ways I can do this with StructureMap? Is there a way to say, when a string "aaa" is listed, then use this value => `"hi!";`

I didn't really want to put all those strings, into a concrete class with an interface.

It's like I want to say something like.

```
For<string>().WithName("aaa").Use<string>().WithValue("hi");
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure( x=>
{
    x.For<FooController2>()
     .Use<FooController2>()
     .Ctor<string>("aaa")
     .Is("hi");
});
```

Comment: ahh .. so instead of using the default controller factory, u're explicitly defining the controller. hmm...

Comment: @Pure.Krome:Afaik the type (FooController2 in this case) has to be registered with the IOC container to be able to pass custom constructor arguments (that's the way it works with Ninject anyway). Also should have been `container` not ObjectFactory

Answer (score 2):

You can register a `Func<T>` delegate, which allows you to have a type safe registration.

```
container.Configure(r => r.For<FooController2>().Use(() =>
{
    var pewPew = container.GetInstance<IPewPew>();  
    return new FooController2(pewPew, "someValue", "anotherValue");
}));
```

Comment: what is an IPewPew in this case? This is just a stock File->New->MVC3 app. an IController? And if i have all my controllers impliment an Abstract Controller .. then IAbstract Controller? Also, what is container? that's the StructureMap object factory? or this not structuremap specific?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: What's an `IPewPew`? That's an odd question, since you should know what it is. It's a dependency of your `FooController2`. You defined that interface in your question.

Comment: The `container` is the `StructureMap.Container` instance, that you would normally create on application startup. But I guess you use the static `ObjectFactory` for registration and don't create an instance manually. In that case, just replace `container` with `ObjectFactory` and you're good to go.